# Where is the layout inspector screenshot button on android studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

It was on logcat tab, but not the snapshot button takes a image snapshot not a layout snapshot.
Where is it now? Was discontinued?

Comment: In `Left Pane in Logcat` with `Camera Icon`

Comment: That is were it was.It is not there now. Read the question please,

Comment: It is Still there only Even For Android Studio 3.0

Comment: same icon, different function. try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now is at menu tools->Android->Layout Inspector.

In case someone found at disable state like me, it may be cause by partial emulator downloaded. In my case started to work after i complete the download and restart the emulator.